# Why am I getting a "String is not NSObject" error in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, string, swift, alamofire

```
let parameters = [
                "alert": model.alert, //Bool
                "distance": model.distance, //Int
                "minAge": model.minAge, //Int
                "maxAge": model.maxAge, //Int
                "access_token": access_token //String
            ]
            Alamofire.request(.POST, Constants.Domain + "/accounts/discovery-settings", parameters: parameters).responseJSON{
                (req, res, json, error) in
            }
```

I did a very similar request previously and it worked.  According to Alamofire, I can set the parameters to anything, right?

Edit:

If I remove these lines, then it compiles just fine. The Bool and Int types seem to be the problem.

```
            "alert": model.alert, //Bool
            "distance": model.distance, //Int
            "minAge": model.minAge, //Int
            "maxAge": model.maxAge, //Int
```

The model is:

```
class DiscoverySettings {
    var alert: Bool
    var distance: Int
    var minAge: Int
    var maxAge: Int
    private init(){
        alert = true
        distance = 10
        minAge = 18
        maxAge = 25
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is this a compile-time or run-time error? On which line does it occur? Is a specific string highlighted? If it's a run-time error, can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: (I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.)

Comment: You can try to write `access_token as NSString`, because NSString is a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: It's a compile error. Access_token isn't the problem. I do the same with another request.

Comment: Seems that these are the problem:                 "alert": model.alert, //Bool
                "distance": model.distance, //Int
                "minAge": model.minAge, //Int
                "maxAge": model.maxAge, //Int . If I remove those, then it compiles.

Comment: can you also post the `model`'s class defination

Comment: I bet the model is an ObjC class

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell since you didn't actually post the error, but I would guess you're having a bridging issue in the dictionary. Give the following a try:

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "alert": model.alert, //Bool
    "distance": model.distance, //Int
    "minAge": model.minAge, //Int
    "maxAge": model.maxAge, //Int
    "access_token": access_token //String
]

let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, Constants.Domain + "/accounts/discovery-settings", parameters: parameters)
request.responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
    println(request)
    println(response)
    println(json)
    println(error)
}
```

Hopefully that helps shed some light. If it doesn't, then please post your actually error and I'll gladly revise my answer.